# Node JS Express Call Multiple APIs and return a Single Response

Tags: node.js, express

I am extremely new to Node, I hope someone can help.
I have 2 APIs that are external to my project.
I want to create a single endpoint in my Node Express server that returns the results from both calls.
How would I do this?

So far I figured out how to call an external resource like this,

```
app.use('/myapi', function(req, res) {  
  var url = 'https://some-service.com/api1';
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});
```

This will return the results to my application. What I cant figure out is how to make a second call, then combine the results into an object like this,

```
{ response1, response2 }
```

Does anyone know how to do this, or point me in the right direction?
Also is there a way to make sure that both calls succeed before sending a response to my application.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you will have to use a method of the promise library that does this, such as 'Promise.all'. It accepts an array of promise objects and resolves with an array of the results.

Comment: Transpose the request into `async` and have the two requests `await`.

Comment: trust me there are lots of articles you will find on internet on how to this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use promise a functionality like this, as the external calls can take their own sweet time. You can wait for the calls to get complete and send the final response.

You can update your route to something like below :

```js
app.use('/myapi', function(req, res) {  
  var url = 'https://some-service.com/api1';
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
  var responseOne =  await CallFirstSystem();
  var responseTwo = await CallSecondSystem();
  var finalResponse  = doSomeLogic(responseOne,responseTwo);
  res.send(finalResponse);
});
```

Create separate functions to call and handle the response

```js
   

function CallFirstSystem() {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            var url = "http://firssytem/api";
            var updateResult = [];
               await axios.get(url, JSON.stringify(requestPayLoad), {
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'                            
                        },
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        updateResult = innerLogicOne(response);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });                
            resolve(updateResult);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } finally {}
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}



function CallSecondSystem() {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            var url = "http://secondSystem/api";
            var updateResult = [];
               await axios.get(url, JSON.stringify(requestPayLoad), {
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'                            
                        },
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        updateResult = innerLogicOne(response);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });                
            resolve(updateResult);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } finally {}
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}
```

I am using axios to call API, you are free to use any other library to call the external system API.

Hope this helps.